# What is the best tool for leveling boards?

Tags: hand-tools

Good day!
A new batch of boards came from the sawmill, but they were in defective. It is necessary to straighten. In general, this situation is very often happening at my work. I used the [Dewalt electric hand planer](https://www.bestadvisor.com/hand-planers) but the last batch (you can see for image) is very large. I need a tool bigger and more powerful, maybe not a hand planer. What do you advise? I think I can ask my superiors about 300 bucks for the right purchase. Thank you!
[image]

Comment: Welcome to WW.SE! Unfortunately, product recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: @mmathis, as I see it this is asking for a tool type, not a specific product recommendation. The post is spam anyway! But would be a legit Question otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

you basically need two tools to do this, a jointer and planer.

the jointer makes on face flat. The planer makes the second face parallel to the first. you can find each for ~ 300 USD, but not both (even used).